# Как отформатировать число в jupyter lab - разделить триады пробелами в pandas?

Tags: python, format, jupyter-lab

Пытаюсь в jupyter lab сделать так, чтобы числа в таблицах были разделены пробелами между триадами. Т.е. нужно: 1 000 000. Никак не получается.
Разделил запятыми:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.float_format = ‘{:,.0f}’.format
```

но надо пробелами. Также пробовал через import locale , но тоже не вышло.
Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы же понимаете, что это вопрос отображения значений, а не их хранения? как бы вы меняли стиль, храниться значения будут так, как им положено, а не так, как вы хоnите, чтобы они выглядели.

в любом случае, можете воспользоваться [стайлерами](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[10000000.15, 23434123.23]})
print(df)
```

```
             a
0  10000000.15
1  23434123.23
```

```
df.style.format(decimal=",", thousands=" ", precision=2)
```

```
    a
0   10 000 000,15
1   23 434 123,23
```

Comment: Это то, что надо! Спасибо!
А скажите, есть ли возможность сделать чтобы такие числа не переносились по пробелам?
Получилось, что у меня много столбцов и при узком экране числа переносятся по пробелам, а не появляется скроллер в таблице...

Comment: ну так увеличьте поле вывода. посмотрите на параметры `pd.set_option('display.max_rows', XXX)`,
`pd.set_option('display.max_columns', XXX)`,
`pd.set_option('display.width', XXX)`

Comment: Так и не смог победить проблему. 
`import pandas as pd`
`import numpy as np`
`df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 50)*1000000)`
`df.style.format(precision=0, thousands=" ", decimal=",")`
Значения в ячейках переносятся по пробелам.
Пытался подобрать опции, но они применяются только, если вывожу датафрейм без стиллера. Т.е. просто `df`. Кроме того, мне надо вывести всю таблицу со скроллерами, т.е. скрыть часть столбцов - не нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел еще вот такое решение:

```
def format_number(x):
    if type(x) == float or type(x) == int:
        return '{:,.0f}'.format(x).replace(',', ' ')
    else:
        return x
df = df.applymap(format_number)
print(df.head())
```